# Update search-index on documentDb changes

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cognitive-search

I want to keep the Azure-Search-Index in sync to my documents stored in Azure-DocumentDB. An Indexer can do that work, but that does not fit to me, because more than on Search-Index has to be updated and the mapping from DocumentDB structure to Index-Scheme is very complicated.

Can I use the DocumentDB triggers to do that?

(Do an http-call -  perhaps to Azure-function - that takes the changed DocumentDB document and calls the Azure-Search Service to update the search indexes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hook the [Cosmos DB Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-cosmos-db-triggered-function) to listen for changes in your collection, process those changes in an Azure Function and send them to Azure Search.

For example, this next function listens for documents, does some simple calculation on the age and sends the batch to Search:

Sample document:

```
{
    "name": "john",
    "born": "1983-05-07",
    "id": "some-id"
}
```

The `run.csx`

```
#r "Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client"
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents;
using Microsoft.Azure.Search;

private static string searchServiceName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SearchServiceName"];
private static string searchServiceKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SearchServiceKey"];
private static SearchServiceClient serviceClient = new SearchServiceClient(searchServiceName, new SearchCredentials(searchServiceKey));
private static ISearchIndexClient indexClient = serviceClient.Indexes.GetClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SearchServiceIndexName"]);

public class IndexItem {
    public string id {get;set;}
    public string name {get;set;}
    public int age {get;set;}
}

public static void Run(IReadOnlyList<Document> documents, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Verbose("Documents modified " + documents.Count);

    if (documents != null && documents.Count > 0)
    {
        var batch = Microsoft.Azure.Search.Models.IndexBatch.MergeOrUpload(documents.Select(
            // Do any transformation needed
            doc => new IndexItem(){
                id = doc.GetPropertyValue<string>("id"),
                name = doc.GetPropertyValue<string>("name"),
                age = CalculateAge(doc.GetPropertyValue<string>("born"))
            }
        ));

        try
        {
            indexClient.Documents.Index(batch);
        }
        catch (IndexBatchException e)
        {
            // Sometimes when your Search service is under load, indexing will fail for some of the documents in
            // the batch. Depending on your application, you can take compensating actions like delaying and
            // retrying. For this simple demo, we just log the failed document keys and continue.            
            log.Error(
                string.Format("Failed to index some of the documents: {0}",
                String.Join(", ", e.IndexingResults.Where(r => !r.Succeeded).Select(r => r.Key))));
            log.Error(e.Message);
        }
    }
}

private static int CalculateAge(string born){
    DateTime bday = DateTime.ParseExact(born,"yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    DateTime now = DateTime.Today;
    var age = now.Year - bday.Year;
    if (bday > now.AddYears(-age)) age--;
    return age;
}
```

You need to add the [Azure Search Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Search) package, for that, add a `project.json` file to your Azure Function:

```
{
  "frameworks": {
    "net46":{
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.Azure.Search": "3.0.5"
      }
    }
   }
}
```